# Sources not loaded , waiting for localhost forever when serving with ssr

Tags: angular, angular-universal, server-side-rendering

After running npm run build:ssr & npm run serve:ssr the app is loading forever  - waiting for localhost  and sources not reloading. 
No errors appeard in the console , The app only run into the console but no views are rendered on the browser.

[see the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmNs8.png)

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" >

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Online store</title>
  <base href="/">
</head>

<body>

  <app-root></app-root>

  <noscript>Please enable JavaScript to continue using this application.</noscript>
  <!-- Custom script -->
  <script>
  </script>
  <!-- Google Analytics Integration -->
  <script>
    (function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
    i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r; i[r] = i[r] || function () {
      (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
    }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date(); a = s.createElement(o),
      m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0]; a.async = 1; a.src = g; m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
    })(window, document, 'script', 'https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');
  </script>
  <!-- End Google Analytics Integration -->

  <!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
  <script>
    !function (f, b, e, v, n, t, s) {
      if (f.fbq) return; n = f.fbq = function () {
        n.callMethod ?
        n.callMethod.apply(n, arguments) : n.queue.push(arguments)
      };
      if (!f._fbq) f._fbq = n; n.push = n; n.loaded = !0; n.version = '2.0';
      n.queue = []; t = b.createElement(e); t.async = !0;
      t.src = v; s = b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];
      s.parentNode.insertBefore(t, s)
    }(window, document, 'script',
      'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
  </script>
  <noscript>
    <img height="1" width="1" style="display:none" src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id="
      +localStorage.getItem('facebookPixelId')+"&ev=PageView&noscript=1" />
  </noscript>
  <!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->
</body>

</html>
```

**package.json**

```
"@angular/core": "^7.2.7",
"@angular/platform-server": "^7.2.7",
"@angular/pwa": "^0.12.4",
"@angular/service-worker": "^7.2.7",
"@nguniversal/express-engine": "^7.1.1",
"@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "^7.1.1",
```

**server.ts**

```
...
app.engine('html', (_, options, callback) => {
  const engine = ngExpressEngine({
    bootstrap: AppServerModuleNgFactory,
    providers: [
      provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP),
      {provide: 'host', useFactory: () => options.req.get('host'), deps: []}
    ]
  });
  engine(_, options, callback);
});

app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser'));

// Serve static files from /browser
app.get('*.*', express.static(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser'), {
  maxAge: '1y'
}));

// All regular routes use the Universal engine
// app.get('*', (req, res) => {
//   res.render('index', {req});
// });

app.get('*', (req, res) => { res.sendFile( join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser' , 'index.html'), {req}); });
```

**tsconfig.server.json**

```
{
"extends": "./tsconfig.app.json",
"compilerOptions": {
 "outDir": "../out-tsc/app-server",
 "baseUrl": "."
},
"angularCompilerOptions": {
 "entryModule": "app/app.server.module#AppServerModule"
}
}
```

**angular.json**

```
....
"server": {
       "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
       "options": {
         "outputPath": "dist/server",
         "main": "src/main.server.ts",
         "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.server.json"
       },
       "configurations": {
         "production": {
           "fileReplacements": [
             {
               "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
               "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
             }
           ]
         }
       }
     }
   ....
```

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
...
"compile:server": "webpack --config webpack.server.config.js --progress --colors",
 "serve:ssr": "node dist/server",
 "build:ssr": "npm run build:client-and-server-bundles && npm run compile:server",
 "build:client-and-server-bundles": "ng build --prod && ng run my-project:server:production",
 "ssr-only": "ng run my-project:server:production && npm run compile:server && node dist/server"
....
}
```

What's wrong in my project?

Answer (score 0):

You are using document and localStorage on server side and that's not available on ssr. That's probably why the page wont load.

Comment: I handled all the DOM/BOM Objects ,Also if so it will crash while the compiling.

Comment: You have localStorage.getItem('facebookPixelId') in the index.html page, that might be the problem.

Comment: No it's not , Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and to solve the problem I had to put the application name after. ie : http://localhost:port/appname